# Help with running the Yesod Development server?

Tags: haskell, ubuntu, ghc, haskell-platform, yesod

I'm currently trying out web development frameworks for haskell and I recently came across [yesod](http://www.yesodweb.com/). It seemed pretty interesting so I installed it using cabal, however I'm not able to run the development server. Following their getting started instructions here's the result:

```
$ yesod init
$ cd mysite
$ yesod devel

Configuring mysite-0.0.0...
Testing files...
Rebuilding app
yesod: bind: resource busy (Address already in use)
Preprocessing library mysite-0.0.0...
Preprocessing executables for mysite-0.0.0...
Building mysite-0.0.0...

Controller.hs:16:7:
    Could not find module `Data.Dynamic':
      It is a member of the hidden package `base'.
      Perhaps you need to add `base' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
      It is a member of the hidden package `base-3.0.3.2'.
      Perhaps you need to add `base' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
      Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Testing files...
Testing files...
^^ above line just keeps repeating...
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the Data.Dynamic module but I don't know how to go about fixing it.

### Additional Info

Running Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick

ghc version:

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 6.12.1
```

Comment: I get 'Could not find module `Prelude`! None of the answers works for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't run into this specific issue, but the error message looks like it's a simple question of GHC being unable to find version 3.0.3.2 the package "base." This version has been buildable since GHC 6.9, so you should have it. Try running the following command:

```
ghc-pkg check
```

This will tell you if there is something wrong with your packages. Cabal can be a bit of a nightmare for dependencies -- partly, it seems, because a lot of Haskell developers underestimate the extent to which their underlying libraries will shift in the future. So they will define a dependency as ">= [version of package x]" without limiting the max version to the one presently available. Or they just leave out version-limiting altogether.

Yesod, I'm happy to say, doesn't fall into this trap. But several of the libraries it depends on do. When you start developing in Haskell, learn this lesson: never assume that future versions of a library won't break your code. They will. A lot.

If ghc-pkg comes up with broken packages, you may need to clean up/uninstall/reinstall these packages until they are either cleaned up or hidden. (Just do `ghc-pkg hide [package name]` to tell ghc to ignore that package.

Your next problem is that hidden base package. Try the following:

```
ghc-pkg list | grep base
```

If you see brackets around the library, that means it's hidden. The package base-3.0.3.2 might show up as hidden (although that's a bit unlikely, as that's where the backward-compatible Prelude lives). If it is hidden, try to unhide it with the following command:

```
ghc-pkg expose base-3.0.3.2
```

Now try re-running `yesod devel` and see how it goes. Best case scenario is that it works. If not, let us know.

Comment: ghc-pkg check lists these: happstack-server-6.0.3, happstack-heist-6.0.1, web-routes-0.24.1, persistent-sqlite-0.5.0, HTTP-4000.0.9
, wai-extra-0.4.0, happstack-6.0.0. When I run ghc-pkg list | grep base, base-3.0.3.2 exists and is not hidden. After trying to reinstall the packages, yesod devel still gives the error.

Comment: happstack probably isn't an issue, as it's a separate system. I'd look closely at persistent-sqlite an wai-extra. But this one's a head scratcher. Make sure you have the executables alex and happy installed and in your path (like, you can run "alex" from the command line and it works). Otherwise, you may have better luck asking the Haskell web-devel mailing list: http://www.haskell.org/mailman/listinfo/web-devel

Comment: For the record, though, yesod has never worked for me -- I always run into Cabal issues like the ones you're dealing with. And I've never yet been particularly motivated to work my way through them. But Michael Snoyman is very active on the web-devel list.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Yesod in Five Minutes guide, you appear to be missing the a call to the command "cabal install" between your "cd mysite" and "yesod devel". It may need to install further packages based on what your responses were during "yesod init", such as which database you want to use.

Also, you *may* want to check that the port is not currently being used, as you have the "Address already in use" shown in your transcript.

Answer (score 0):

First, it would be a good idea to resolve any broken packages reported by ghc-pkg check, by removing/reinstalling/upgrading them.

Next, can you manually cabal build the mysite app without trouble ? If your mysite.cabal actually does not specify base in the build-depends list, you should follow the suggestion to add that.

The repeating Testing Files message is normal for current yesod devel, it is polling your source files.